# How to make my rock, paper, scissors game more efficient?

Tags: python

New programmer here. I am writing a rock, paper scissors game, so far I
have managed to get it working, however I'm wondering how I could make
it more efficient. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions :)

```
 import random



 choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
 result1 = random.choice(choices)
 result2 = random.choice(choices)

 print('player one has chosen ' + result1)
 print('player two has chosen ' + result2)

 if result1 == result2:
     print('draw!')
```

In particular does anyone know if the code below can be simplified?

```
 elif result1 == choices[0] and result2 == choices[1]:
     print('player two wins!')


 elif result1 == choices[0] and result2 == choices[2]:
     print('player one wins!')

 elif result1 == choices[1] and result2 == choices[2]:
     print('player two wins!')

 elif result1 == choices[1] and result2 == choices[0]:
     print('player two wins!')

 elif result1 == choices[2] and result2 == choices[0]:
     print('player one wins!')

 elif result1 == choices[2] and result2 == choices[1]:
     print('player one wins!')
```

Comment: I dunno about efficient. Perhaps you mean idiomatic or readable?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-paper-scissors

Comment: I'm not sure, I mean repeating less code and doing the same thing but with fewer lines of code.

Comment: `def who_wins(result1, result2): return ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to define the possible wins, for example using a dictionary,

```
import random

choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
wins = {'rock': 'scissors',
        'paper': 'rock',
        'scissors': 'paper'}

result1 = random.choice(choices)
result2 = random.choice(choices)

print('player one has chosen ' + result1)
print('player two has chosen ' + result2)

if result1 == result2:
    print('draw!')
elif result1 == wins[result2]:
    print('player two wins')
else:
    print('player one wins')
```

Example:

```
player one has chosen scissors
player two has chosen rock
player two wins
```

###### generalization

This makes it easy to generalize to a more complex situation, for instance rock/paper/scissors/lizard/Spock:

```
import random

wins = {'rock': set(['scissors', 'lizard']),
        'paper': set(['rock', 'spock']),
        'scissors': set(['paper', 'lizard']),
        'lizard': set(['spock', 'paper']),
        'spock': set(['rock', 'scissors'])
       }
choices = list(wins)

result1 = random.choice(choices)
result2 = random.choice(choices)

print('player one has chosen ' + result1)
print('player two has chosen ' + result2)

if result1 == result2:
    print('draw!')
elif result1 in wins[result2]:
    print('player two wins')
else:
    print('player one wins')
```

Example:

```
player one has chosen spock
player two has chosen scissors
player one wins
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` operator -

```
elif (result1 == choices[1] and result2 == choices[2]) or (result1 == choices[1] and result2 == choices[0]) or (result1 == choices[0] and result2 == choices[1]):
     print('player two wins!')
elif (result1 == choices[2] and result2 == choices[0]) or (result1 == choices[2] and result2 == choices[1]) or (result1 == choices[0] and result2 == choices[2]):
     print('player one wins!')
```